# MS-Access query to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CASE equivalent of a nested IIF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313616/case-equivalent-of-a-nested-iif-statement)

I'm trying to convert the following Access query into T-SQL, but I'm having problems with IIF statement.

**ACCESS Query**

```
SELECT 
qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2.Asset AS SITE_REF,
Format([Det],"00000") AS DET_, 
IIf(IsNull([MT]),"0",IIf(Right([SP_Ref],2)="WZ"
And IsNull([LabLoadFileSuffix_MT]) 
And [MT]>0,CStr([MT]) & "CT",CStr([MT]) & [LabLoadFileSuffix_MT])) AS MT_COUNT,  
IIf(IIf(IsNull([MT]),0,[MT])>=IIf(IsNull([IM]),0,[IM]),0,
IIf(IsNull([IM]),"0",IIf(Right([SP_Ref],2)="WZ" 
And IsNull([LabLoadFileSuffix_IM]),CStr([IM]) 
& "CT",CStr([IM]) & [LabLoadFileSuffix_IM]))) AS IM_COUNT,   
qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2.[2012 Sample Point] AS SP_REF, qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2.Area
FROM qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2
WHERE (((IIf(IsNull([IM]),0,[IM])+IIf(IsNull([MT]),0,[MT]))>0));
```

I've tried to convert a part of it. Can anyone help me correct the nested IID statement as I'm not sure.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2.Asset AS SITE_REF,
RIGHT('00000' + CAST([Det] AS VARCHAR(5)),5) AS DET_,
  ----- (the nested iff statements)
qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2.[2012 Sample Point] AS SP_REF,
qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2.Area
FROM qry_LAB_LOAD_Prequery2
where (ISNull([IM],0) + ISNULL([MT],0)) > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the nested IIF you need user CASE.

Lets take the first one:

Reformating I get:

```
IIf(
          IsNull([MT]),
          "0",
                   IIf(Right([SP_Ref],2)="WZ"
                            And IsNull([LabLoadFileSuffix_MT]) 
                            And [MT]>0,

                        CStr([MT]) & "CT",
                        CStr([MT]) & [LabLoadFileSuffix_MT]
                    )
    ) AS MT_COUNT,
```

It Converts to :

```
CASE
WHEN [MT] IS NULL 
    THEN "0",
ELSE
    CASE 
        WHEN Right([SP_Ref],2) = "WZ"
           AND ([LabLoadFileSuffix_MT] IS NULL
               AND [MT]>0
        THEN 
             CAST([MT] AS VARCHAR) + "CT"
        ELSE
             CAST([MT] AS VARCHAR) + [LabLoadFileSuffix_MT]
    END
END AS MT_COUNT,
```

Which simplifies to :

```
CASE
WHEN [MT] IS NULL 
    THEN "0",
ELSE
    CAST([MT] AS VARCHAR)  
   + CASE 
        WHEN Right([SP_Ref],2) = "WZ"
           AND ([LabLoadFileSuffix_MT] IS NULL
               AND [MT]>0
        THEN 
             "CT"
        ELSE
             [LabLoadFileSuffix_MT]
    END
END AS MT_COUNT,
```

For tee second one I reformatted and then converted it to the following

```
CASE WHEN 

    CASE 
      WHEN [MT] IS NULL THEN 0 
      ELSE [MT] 
    END 

     >=

    CASE 
      WHEN [IM] IS NULL THEN 0 
      ELSE [IM] 
    END ,

 THEN   0,
 ELSE    

   CASE 
      WHEN [IM] IS NULL THEN "0" 
      ELSE 

        CASE 
          WHEN Right([SP_Ref],2) = "WZ" AND [LabLoadFileSuffix_IM] IS NULL THEN CAST([IM] AS VARCHAR) + "CT"
          ELSE CAST([IM] AS VARCHAR) + [LabLoadFileSuffix_IM]
        END
      END
 END
 AS IM_COUNT,
```

Whick reduces to

```
CASE 
      WHEN ISNULL([MT], 0) > =  ISNULL([IM], 0)
 THEN   0,
 ELSE    
   CASE 
      WHEN [IM] IS NULL THEN "0" 
      ELSE 
        CAST([IM] AS VARCHAR) +
        CASE 
          WHEN Right([SP_Ref],2) = "WZ" AND [LabLoadFileSuffix_IM] IS NULL THEN "CT"
          ELSE  [LabLoadFileSuffix_IM]
        END
      END
 END
 AS IM_COUNT,
```

Which essentially boils down to 2 very similar expressions for both columns.

Comment: Thanks Preet. Any idea on the second iff statement?

Comment: I've converted that second one too.

Answer (score 1):

Try a nested case statement.

So just taking the first 2 of your lines:

```
IIf(IsNull([MT]),"0",IIf(Right([SP_Ref],2)="WZ"
And IsNull([LabLoadFileSuffix_MT])
```

would become

```
CASE WHEN MT IS NULL 
THEN 0
ELSE
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(SP_Ref, 2) = "WZ" AND LabLoadFileSuffix_MT IS NULL 
    THEN
         ...
    ELSE ...
    END
END
```